# type of dynamically accessed property in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function I want to reuse that is applicable on multiple properties of a custom type.
Something like this:

```
interface MyType {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}
type MyTypeKey = keyof MyType;

const testValue = (
  obj: MyType,
  property: MyTypeKey,
  value: any, // <-- what type should go here?
) => {
  if (obj[property] === value) {
    console.log("do something");
  }
}

testValue({prop1: "a", prop2: 1}, "prop1", "okay"); // should be okay
testValue({prop1: "a", prop2: 1}, "prop2", "oops"); // should be error
```

But I don't know how to do this since I don't know the type of the property value. How can I solve this?

(I am new to javascript/typescript, so forgive me for small typos and constructions and bad practices)

Comment: As part of the process for being forgiven for typos, you can [edit] the post to remove them so that they do not distract from the question (or you can let me do it).  I suggest you use the version [presented here](https://tsplay.dev/N912VN).  Is that acceptable?

Comment: I edited the post to your version, thanks for the improvement of my example!

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic argument to indicate the key. From that key you can look it up on `MyType` to get the associated value's type, and require that the `value` argument to the generic function be that type.

```
interface MyType {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

const testValue = <K extends keyof MyType>(
    obj: MyType,
    property: K,
    value: MyType[K],
) => {
    if (obj[property] === value) {
        // ...
    }
}

declare const obj: MyType;
// OK
testValue(obj, 'prop2', 3);
// Not OK
testValue(obj, 'prop2', 'a');
```

For a more flexible function that can validate any sort of object, without hard-coding `MyType` into it, make another generic type for the object.

```
const testValue = <O extends object, K extends keyof O>(
    obj: O,
    property: K,
    value: O[K],
) => {
    if (obj[property] === value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```